# Symfony2 Where to save Environment Variables

Tags: php, apache, symfony, variables, environment

I've seen plenty of tutorials on configuring an Apache2 virtual host with environment variables and using those variables as a parameter within the site. However, the issue I'm having is when I run php app/console cache:clear or reload my data fixtures, I get the following error:
You have requested a non-existent parameter ...

If I first export the parameter prior to reloading my fixtures, the error goes away as the environment variable is set. Which makes sense as that function isn't using Apache to execute and needs the environment variable set. But this doesn't fix my issue when I clear my cache manually.

So my question is, where do I actually want to save those environment variables?

I would like to store site specific information that's dependent on which virtual host is used.

I could store them in my ~/.profile bash file, but that doesn't really make sense and all of the documentation I've read simply says store with the virtual host (for Apache). But none of those docs mention executing scripts outside of a web browser accessing the site such as reloading fixtures, running migrations, or clearing cache, which is only an issue when I deploy my source.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: So I may have figured it out, though I would like someone to chime in if this isn't correct. When clearing the cache, I'm now running `php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup`, the difference being the --no-warmup option. For reloading my fixtures, I've created a script that first exports the environment variables (default ones), then reloads my fixtures. Is this the proper way to store the environment variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put application variables in `app/config/config.yml`. You can put there:

```
parameters:
    your.parameter.1: value1
    your.parameter.2: value2
```

If you use any kind of version control system you can exclude those variables to separate file and ignore this file in version control repository. You also should include this file in config.yml. For example if you put the above variables in `app/config/example.yml` then you should add in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
imports:
- { resource: example.yml }
```

**EDIT**

You can always put parameters as follows:

```
parameters:
    domain1:
       param1: value1
       param2: value2
    domain2:
       param1: value1
       param2: value2
    domain3:
       param1: value1
       param2: value2
```

and then read these variables in places where you want to use them according to the current domain or you can also set service that sets common variables according to current domain. For command line you can use default values.

Comment: Sorry, but what I need is to have the variable come from the specific virtual host, as there will be multiple incoming calls from various hosts. Thank you though.

Comment: So why don't you simply use request reading? Can you give an example of such variable? I updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Well the task then becomes, checking the host var for which domain is loaded and performing a little bit of logic to figure out which parameter domain to use. Where if I'm able to use an environment variable set in the apache virtual host, I don't have to perform that logic and the variables are automatically set as a parameter.

Comment: For an example, if a user hits the site domain1.site.com, the parameter site-id is set to 1, or if domain2.site.com is hit, site-id is to 2.

Comment: Virtual host variables are suitable only for requests on HTTP. As far as I understand those variables are also needed when you are out of HTTP request context. In general there is no difference between keeping variables in config.yml and in virtual hosts because in both cases you have to set some default values. Despite that if you set those variables in config.yml you keep information inside of application. Moreover since you can read parameters from every place in your application there is no additional logic to implement at all.

Comment: Ultimately I took Grzgorz advice and stored all of the data in config.yml files and stopped using ENV VARs in apache. I used the guidance provided by KNP Universtiry, http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-dynamic-subdomains, to get the host name, which will ultimately determine what site data is used. This also simplified pushing to production (I use Capifony, which used to complain of those ENV VARs not being set) and running cron jobs on the site. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So just because this is situation is a pet peeve of mine I urge you not to put environment specific information in the config file. So what is needed are two files that must stay in sync. One file will be for command line and one for Apache (or HTTP server of your choice) environment variables

```
CL: /var/www/applications/coolapp/coolapp.sh
Apache: /var/www/applications/coolapp/coolapp.apache.conf
```

## Usage

For the command line, any time I run a Symfony command I source my environment (this example is for bash shell)

```
$ . ./coolapp.sh
$ app/console cache:clear
```

In the Apache config for the site I add an include such as
/etc/httpd/conf.d/coolapp.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost coolapp.local:443>
...
Include /var/www/applications/coolapp/coolapp.apache.conf
...
</VirtualHost>
```

What is in these files?

coolapp.sh would contain something like

```
export SYMFONY__APP_USER = foo
export SYMFONY__APP_PASS = foobar01
```

and coolapp.conf would have

```
SetEnv SYMFONY__APP_USER fop
SetEnv SYMFONY__APP_PASS foobar01
```

So each one of my environments (production, qa, stage, test, dev, localdev) would have these two files. And they can be changed whenever without going into the code.
Within Symfony you would access these variable like

```
%app_user%
%app_pass%
```

Comment: This is against DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself.. main aim of which is to reduce repetition of code.

Comment: To conform to DRY, what you could do is create a script that would replace the coolapp.sh and would suck in the Apache coolapp.conf file, convert the text from "Apache Config" to "Bash Environment" format and set the users environment. Good luck with that.